# With nginx loadbalancer, do clients get redistributed after a member recovers?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

Suppose I have a simple setup where nginx is being used as a load balancer for two servers, using the `ip_hash` option.

```
upstream backend {
  ip_hash;

  server backend1.example.com;
  server backend2.example.com;
}
```

Clients will be distributed across the two servers based on the client IP.

Now suppose `backend1` goes down. Clients that were previously sent to `backend1` based on their hash will now get directed to `backend2`. That's fine. What happens later, when `backend1` returns? Will all of the clients get 'stuck' on `backend2`? Or will the ones that were originally on `backend1` migrate back?

I've looked at the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash), but the behavior is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for the [upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) show options for

```
max_fails=number
```

> sets the number of unsuccessful attempts to communicate with the server that should happen in the duration set by the fail_timeout parameter to consider the server unavailable for a duration also set by the fail_timeout parameter. By default, the number of unsuccessful attempts is set to 1

```
fail_timeout=time
```

> the time during which the specified number of unsuccessful attempts to communicate with the server should happen to consider the server unavailable;
>   and the period of time the server will be considered unavailable.
>   By default, the parameter is set to 10 seconds.

Based on that, I have always believed that once you hit you `max_fails` threshold that nginx would offline that server for the `fail_timeout` then after the `fail_timeout` it would be placed back into service.